# What's the difference of *.tpl and *.html in smarty?

Tags: html, smarty, task-parallel-library

I didn't find the document about this.

Answer (score 3):

I really think this is up to the developer to choose an extention. I do not think there is a difference in functionality selecting one over another. I thik it is more a convention that .html is used for ready-to-render web pages, but .tpl indicates that the file is a template.

My experience comes from Dwoo, but the syntax and the file extension are basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. Using *.tpl for template files is just a convention. You can use any other extension.